# Expressing an instance for any type that satisfies multiple constraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I suspect that all applicative, foldable monoids are traversable in the same manner. In other words, for any type `t :: * -> *` that satisfies `Applicative` and `Foldable`, and for which all instantiations `t a` satisfy `Monoid`, there is a free instance of `Traversable`.

Here is how I would implement `sequenceA`:

```haskell
sequenceA :: (Applicative t, Foldable t, Monoid (t a), Applicative f) =>
  t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA = foldl (liftA2 $ \b a -> mappend b (pure a)) (pure mempty)
```

We can e.g. use this to traverse a list containing functions into a function that will produce a list (since `[]` is applicative, foldable, and a monoid for all types `[a]`):

```haskell
sequenceA [\a -> 2 * a, \a -> 2 + a] $ 5
-- [10, 7]
```

---

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to actually specify a `Traversable` instance with this implementation of `sequenceA`. Here's what I tried:

```haskell
instance (Applicative t, Foldable t, Monoid (t a)) => Traversable t where
  sequenceA = foldl (liftA2 $ \b a -> mappend b (pure a)) (pure mempty)
```

If I try to compile this without any extensions I get:

```
<interactive>:3:55: error:
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘Traversable t’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘(Traversable t)’
```

What is the correct way for me to express this instance in Haskell?

---

On the off chance that recursively adding whatever extensions the compiler errors mention might fix the problem, I tried that out and have pasted the results [here](https://gist.github.com/masaeedu/d392178a7691e9955bf4b14c8eac321a). If any of the error messages there are relevant, please let me know and I'll move them directly into the question body.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `FlexibleInstances`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yes, see the linked gist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture is wrong. Consider the type

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Monoid hiding ((<>))

newtype FL a = FL [a] deriving (Functor, Foldable, Applicative)
instance Semigroup (FL a) where
  FL as <> FL bs = FL $ as ++ drop (length as) bs
instance Monoid (FL a) where
  mempty = FL []
  mappend = (<>)
```

This is based on the `Alternative` instance for `ZipList`. `mempty` is obviously the identity for `mappend`, and `mappend` is somewhat less obviously associative, so it's a valid `Monoid` instance. However, it does *not* lead to a valid `Traversable` instance using your definition. Your definition works for lists (and a few other types, like `Data.Sequence.Seq` and `Data.Vector.Vector`) because they have a very special structure.

In particular, `[a]` is (modulo some laziness considerations) the *free monoid* over `a` with `pure` and `foldMap` satisfying a particular universal property:

> Whenever `m` is a `Monoid` and `f :: a -> m`, `foldMap f` is the unique monoid homomorphism such that `foldMap f . pure = f`.

In other situations, such as `FL` above, you're generally not going to end up satisfying the identity law for `Traversable`, although I suppose you might find somewhat weaker conditions under which it works out.

---

What if you want to muck about with your idea anyway? The easiest thing is to replace the `Monoid (t a)` constraint with an `Alternative t` constraint. Then you can use `empty` instead of `mempty` and `(<|>)` instead of `mappend`, and the types (although not the laws) should work out.

If you're really stuck on `Monoid`, you have to bring in some much heavier machinery from [`Data.Constraint.Forall`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/Data-Constraint-Forall.html). What you want to say is that for each `a`, `Monoid (t a)`. You can express that as `ForallF Monoid t`. But you can't just use `Monoid` methods under that constraint, because it's not natively supported by `GHC`. Rather, you'll have to use `instF`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables, InstanceSigs, ... #-}

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Forall

instance (Applicative t, Foldable t, ForallF Monoid t)
  => Traversable t where
  sequenceA :: forall f a. Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
  sequenceA =
   case instF :: ForallF Monoid t :- Monoid (t a) of
     Sub Dict -> foldl (liftA2 $ \b a -> mappend b (pure a)) (pure mempty)
```

Of course, once you've gone to all that trouble, you'll discover that your `Traversable` instance overlaps with *every other* `Traversable` instance, which is pretty much a total disaster.

Addendum: as [Benjamin Hodgson notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110614/expressing-an-instance-for-any-type-that-satisfies-multiple-constraints/50111137?noredirect=1#comment87251975_50111137), there is an accepted [GHC proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0018-quantified-constraints.rst) to support quantified (and implication) constraints. When that is implemented (likely to be soon), you'll be able to simply write `forall a. Monoid (t a)` as a constraint, and things should work out much more easily.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that if/when `QuantifiedConstraints` arrives in GHC then `ForallF` will become obsolete (and programming with such constraints will be much easier)

Comment: I guess the second part of this is really the answer to the question, still trying to understand the first bit. When you say "Whenever m is a `Monoid` and `f :: a -> m`, `foldMap f` ...", isn't that first clause a given for any `f` you can pass to `foldMap`? Or is this asserting some special property I'm not understanding?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, look at the explanation of [the universal property of the free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Universal_property) on Wikipedia. The universal property of a monoid is the same (just substitute monoid everywhere). In that explanation, `pure` serves as the inclusion mapping and `foldMap f` plays the role of their φ. The point is that lists and the like have an interesting relationship among their `Monoid`, `Applicative`, and `Foldable` instances that does not need to exist in general, and in the general case they don't come together to form a valid `Traversable`.

Comment: In the above comment, I meant "The universal property of a *free* monoid is the same, with monoid substituted for group everywhere." @AsadSaeeduddin, do you understand what I was getting at now?

Comment: @dfeuer I'm sorry, I haven't had time to look at the Wikipedia article or your comment in depth yet, I'm planning to do that this weekend. In a time crunch at work right now.

Comment: My surface level understanding so far is that you could possibly write a monoid subclass with some extra laws, and for any lawful instance of *that subclass* (instead of vanilla `Monoid`s) you can legally do the traversable thing above.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, I think you'd be better off dropping `Applicative` and adding `class (Foldable t, ForallF Monoid t) => FreeMonoid t where inject :: a -> t a` with the appropriate laws.

Comment: @dfeuer That makes sense. I had the sense that `Applicative` was overkill since we don't have any use for the `lift2`/`ap` here, but couldn't find a "pointed" superclass of it.

Comment: I went over things and it makes much more sense now, thanks. I was wondering if this has anything to do with the fact that depending on `Foldable` here sort of "overconstrains" things, in that I'm deriving traversable from foldable as one of the ingredients, but a foldable may be derived from that traversable as well. The only valid solution is one where the free foldable you get from the traversable is identical to the one you put in, and it just so happens the only monoid with a satisfactory interaction with `foldMap` is the free monoid?